# Automorphisms of a projective plane curve of the form $Y^3Z = f(X,Z)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $C : Y^3Z = f(X,Z)$, with $f(X,Z)\in K[X,Z]$ a homogeneous polynomial of degree $4$, assume $C$ is a smooth plane quartic.

$C$ clearly has an automorphism of the form $(x,y,z)\mapsto (x,\omega y, z)$, with $\omega^3 = 1$. My question is: could it have any more automorphisms? Or, alternatively, under what conditions on $f(X,Z)$, would it have no other automorphisms?

EDIT: as pointed out in the comments, there are special cases in which the curve has additional automorphisms, so my question is, under what conditions are there no additional automorphisms.

Comment: If $f(X,Z) = (X^2 - aZ^2)(X^2 - bZ^2)$, there are more automorphisms.

Comment: I guess generically there aren't, I'm not sure how to approach that however